# Keeping the item named 'other' at the bottom of my ordered list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of SelectListItems like this:

```
List<SelectListItem> test = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text="aaa", Value ="1"},
    new SelectListItem { Text="ttt", Value="2"},
    new SelectListItem { Text="bbb", Value = "3"},
    new SelectListItem { Text="other", Value = "4"}
}.OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

This above code return the ordered list like this:

- aaa
- bbb
- other
- ttt

I would like to order my list but keep the item named 'other' at the bottom of the list.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will work

```
List<SelectListItem> test = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text="aaa", Value ="1"},
    new SelectListItem { Text="ttt", Value="2"},
    new SelectListItem { Text="bbb", Value = "3"},
    new SelectListItem { Text="other", Value = "4"}
}.OrderBy(x => x.Text == "other").ThenBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe the best approach!